# C code : Warning when converting strings to uppercase

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm programming a STM32 device in C using SIM32CudeIDE.

I want to convert lower case characters in a string to upper, leaving the string in its current place. I "stole" the code below from online, however I get a  warning...operation on '*String' may be undefined. The function works ok, how do I modify this to get rid of the warning.

My code is

```
void StrToUpperCase(char *String)
{

    while (*String)
    {
        *String = (*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z') ? *String = *String - 0x20 : *String;
        String++;
    }

}
```

Comment: (a) Edit the code to provide a [mre]. When I compile the code, with elevated warnings, I do not get any warnings. If your compiler is producing the message because of how the routine is called, we need to see the calling code. (b) Do not use code copied from some online source that you do not understand.

Comment: Call `toupper(3)` in a loop.

Comment: @Haris: that will not fix a problem of `String` being undefined or uninitialized.

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner to write `*String -= (...) ? 0x20 : 0`, but this is terrible advice because this whole thing should just use `toupper`

Comment: @ElecDesigner,  Why code `*String = *String - 0x20` and not `*String - 0x20`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell if you want even shorter, just do `*String -= (...) * 0x20;`

Comment: We need to see the actual warnings from the compiler. Also, you can't call this code with a string literal.

Comment: if you get rid of unecessary part `*String = ` in   `*String = *String - 0x20`, does gcc still report the same warning ?

Comment: Specify the compiler you are using (not just the IDE) and the switches used to compile. One possibility is the compiler is recognizing that the behavior of `*String = … *String = …` is undefined since it modifies `*String` twice without sequencing, and it is reporting that as “operation on '*String' may be undefined”, which is not a good error message for that situation. If so, you should not expect that “The function works ok”; you should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `*String = (*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z') ? *String = *String - 0x20 : *String;` is not defined by the C standard because it contains two assignments to `*String` for which the updates of `*String` are not sequenced, violating C 2018 6.5 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…

To fix this, the unnecessary interior assignment should be removed:

```
*String = (*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z') ? *String - 0x20 : *String;
```

There remain other issues with the code, notably that `>= 'a'`, `<= 'z'`, and `0x20` are dependent on a particular character set encoding. At the very least, assuming there is some reason for not using the standard `toupper` function and that we can assume the uppercase and the lowercase letters are each contiguous and in the same order, the code is better written as:

```
if (*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z')
    *String += 'A' - 'a';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `StrToUpperCase()`  with a *string literal* like `StrToUpperCase("Hello");` as attempting to change  a string literal is *undefined behavior* (UB). [@CoffeeTableEspresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76006676/c-code-warning-when-converting-strings-to-uppercase/76006991#comment134052889_76006676).

---

The 2 assignments in code is strange:

```
//      v                                              v                                    
*String = (*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z') ? *String = *String - 0x20 : *String;
```

1 assignment would make more sense and may squash the warning:

```
*String = (*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z') ? *String - 0x20 : *String;
```

---

Better to upper code (reduce magic numbers):

```
*String = (*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z') ? *String - 'a' + 'A' : *String;
```

---

Even better to upper code:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *StrToUpperCase(char *str) {
  //  toupper() designed for unsigned char values (and EOF)
  unsigned char *ustr = (unsigned char *) str;
  while (*ustr) {
    *ustr = toupper(*ustr);
    ustr++;
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The side effect of the left-most `*String =`  is unsequenced in relation to another side effect on the same variable, namely `*String = *String - 0x20`. So your code invokes undefined behavior.

The `?:` operator works as first evaluating the first operand (to the left), then there is a sequence point between that one and the evaluation of the second or third operand.

However, an expression `*String = op1 ? op2 :op3;` is by operator precedence equivalent to `*String = (op1 ? op2 : op3);` and if either `op2` or `op3` happen to modify `*String` as well, it is undefined behavior since there's no sequence point between `op2`/`op3` and `*String =` .

---

Solution:

Contrary to popular belief, most operators on a single line does not win a price. Rather, clean readable code wins a price:

```
for(size_t i=0; String[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
  if(String[i] >= 'a' && String[i] <= 'z')
  {
    String[i] -= 0x20;
  }
}
```

This is still problematic because arithmetic on characters in the character table isn't well-defined for any other character but `'0'` to `'9'`. Rewriting the code again, we can fix that too:

```
#include <ctype.h>

for(size_t i=0; String[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
  String[i] = toupper(String[i]);
}
```

`toupper` being well-defined to only change characters it recognizes as lower case (ironically, it very likely does this internally by masking away 0x20 but no guarantees).

Comment: Corner: `toupper();` is a problem when `String[i] < 0` and not `EOF`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well yeah that's the same old story with all ctype.h functions and casting to `unsigned char` is the solution. However, I think the OP here is just a beginner trying to figure out how these functions work behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

This an example why saving the keyboard and writing "hacky" code is never a good decision. Write it in more lines, do not use magic numbers, and return the value to use it in another function calls.

```
char *StrToUpperCase(char *String)
{
    char *saved = String;
    if(String)
    {
        while (*String)
        {
            if(*String >= 'a' && *String <= 'z')
            {
                *String += 'A' - 'a';
            }
            String++;
        }
    }
    return saved;
}
```

It is much easier to read, debug and maintain

https://godbolt.org/z/edrodYeYx

But much better is to use standard library function `toupper`

Comment: Is this less efficient as we are making another copy of the string?

Answer (score 0):

`Exclusive Or` work fine too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



char *Upper(char *str) {
  unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) str;
  while (*p) {
    if(*p>='a'&&*p<='z'){
        *p=*p^32;
    }
    p++;
  }
  return str;
}
char *Lower(char *str) {
  unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) str;
  while (*p) {
    if(*p>='A'&&*p<='Z'){
        *p=*p^32;
    }
    p++;
  }
  return str;
}
char *SwitchLowerUpper(char *str) {
  unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) str;
  while (*p) {
    if((*p>='A'&&*p<='Z') || (*p>='a'&&*p<='z')){
        *p=*p^32;
    }
    p++;
  }
  return str;
}
int main() {
    char test[]="aBcDef";
    printf("%s\n",Upper(test));
    printf("%s\n",Lower(test));
    char test2[]="aBcDef";
    printf("%s\n",SwitchLowerUpper(test2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*p &= ~0x20` is more readable and self-documenting code, however.